# using remoteio together with AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

Tags: iphone, audio, audiotoolbox

we are trying to use remoteio for audio recording in conjunction
with the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function for audio playback. the problem is that whenever remoteio is running the playback volume drops
significantly. it seems like if some final mixing takes place behind the scene but we do not no how to change this behavior.

the implementation of the remoteio is based on the fallowing blog
http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

for audio playback we just use code like this one

```
NSString *sndPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"wav" inDirectory:@"/"];
CFURLRef sndURL = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sndPath];
SystemSoundID soundID;

int e = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(sndURL, &soundID);
if (e) {
  NSLog(@"couldn't create sound");
  exit(0);
}
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

You may have to disable the voice processing AGC.